# How to prevent movement of modal on arraw keys in kendo grid using jquery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on kendo grid. Below is the example of popup editing which includes code snippet link. Here, the kendo grid provides me a popup on click of **Add new record** button. When I press arrow keys(right, left, up, down) the popup moves in the direction of pressed arrow. I want to prevent the popup movement on arrow(right, left, up, down) keys.

[Popup Link](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in options for that, but you can prevent window key navigation by removing windows tab indexes on window open event.

```
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    window: {
        title: "My Custom Title",
        animation: false,
        open: function() {
           $(".k-window").add(".k-window-content").attr("tabindex", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Working example: [kendo grid editable popup](https://dojo.telerik.com/uCagUveJ)

Or if you do not need draggable window you can disable that and keys navigation wont work anymore:

```
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    window: {
        title: "My Custom Title",
        animation: false,
        draggable: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have used last option of draggable: false